# How to disable previous date in ngbDatepicker in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, date, angular4-forms

I want to disable all the previous/past date in `ngbDatepicker`,
I have used `ngbDatepicker`.
My HTML is:

```
<input required class="form-control" placeholder="dd-MM-YYYY" name="startDate" required ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker"
            [readonly]="true" [formControl]="formModel.controls.startDate" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!formModel.controls['startDate'].valid && formModel.controls['startDate'].touched}" />
```

Answer (score 7):

You could create an Implementation of NgbDatepickerConfig specifying when  starts and ends your picker.

Here you have an example:

**Html**:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp"[markDisabled]="isDisabled" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button">
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
constructor(config: NgbDatepickerConfig) { 

    const currentDate = new Date();

    config.minDate = {year:currentDate.getFullYear(), month:currentDate.getMonth()+1, day: currentDate.getDate()};
    config.maxDate = {year: 2099, month: 12, day: 31};

    config.outsideDays = 'hidden';
  }
```

You can also disable specific dates using this feature, follow this [link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/example) for more info, check: 'Global configuration of datepickers' section.

Comment: How do you handle for two datepicker. How will you register config for each date picker with different minimum date

Comment: @SanJaisy I answered your question

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for being late. I just came across this question, and the above answer that mutates the properties of `NgbDatcConfig`. That solution works fine, but it will affect all the other `NgbDatepicker` instances. The recommended way to do so would be to make use of the `[minDate]` input binding as stated on the [API](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api).

You can use it this way on your component.html,

```
 <input class="form-control" ngbDatepicker [minDate]="minDate" (click)="datePicker.toggle()" #datePicker="ngbDatepicker"" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd">
```

And on your component.ts, you can define `minDate` in this manner:

```
minDate = undefined;
.
. 
constructor(private config: NgbDatepickerConfig) {
  const current = new Date();
  this.minDate = {
    year: current.getFullYear(),
    month: current.getMonth() + 1,
    day: current.getDate()
  };
}
```