# Disable Dependent Date picker Angular Power Bootstrap angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular5, angular6

I, am trying to disable dependent date picker power by bootstrap angular. My requirement is Select a date from first date picker. After that disable the past date from the selected date picker on another date picker.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Risk Windows (Start Date)</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" formControlName="riskWindowStartDate" ngbDatepicker #d1="ngbDatepicker">
         <div class="input-group-append">
         <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="d1.toggle()" type="button">
            <i class="fas fa-calendar"></i>
         </button>
    </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="f.riskWindowStartDate.invalid && (f.riskWindowStartDate.dirty || f.riskWindowStartDate.touched)" class="invalid-feedback">
     <div *ngIf="f.riskWindowStartDate.errors.required"> Risk Window Start Date is a required field.
     </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Another Date Picker**

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label>Risk Windows (End Date)</label>
     <div class="input-group">
         <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" formControlName="riskWindowEndDate" ngbDatepicker #d2="ngbDatepicker">
          <div class="input-group-append">
               <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="d2.toggle()" type="button">
                   <i class="fas fa-calendar"></i>
                </button>
           </div>
     </div>
     <div *ngIf="f.riskWindowEndDate.invalid && (f.riskWindowEndDate.dirty || f.riskWindowEndDate.touched)" class="invalid-feedback">
           <div *ngIf="f.riskWindowEndDate.errors.required"> Risk Window End Date is a required field. 
           </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

I, did some research and found that, need to add minDate and maxDate as per the official document. But not able to found how to solve the dependent date selected.

[image: image display]

As per the image the second datepicker date need to be disable from the 2018-08-16.

Some research link 
[How to disable previous date in ngbDatepicker in Angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49559718/how-to-disable-previous-date-in-ngbdatepicker-in-angular-4)

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples

Answer (score 1):

End up finding this solution

**First datepicker**

```
<div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" formControlName="riskWindowStartDate" ngbDatepicker #d1="ngbDatepicker" (dateSelect)="onDateSelection($event)">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="d1.toggle()" type="button">
                        <i class="fas fa-calendar"></i>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

**Second DatePicker**

```
<div class="form-group">
                  <label>Risk Windows (End Date)</label>
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" formControlName="riskWindowEndDate" [minDate]="minDate" ngbDatepicker #d2="ngbDatepicker">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="d2.toggle()" type="button">
                        <i class="fas fa-calendar"></i>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div *ngIf="f.riskWindowEndDate.invalid && (f.riskWindowEndDate.dirty || f.riskWindowEndDate.touched)" class="invalid-feedback">
                  </div>
                </div>
```

**ts file**

```
minDate: any;

  onDateSelection(evt: any) {
    this.minDate = { year: evt.year, month: evt.month, day: evt.day };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Disabling dates in the ng-bootstrap date picker is not supported by default. It's better add validation to allow user to select custom date ranges.

Comment: Here is the stackblitz code. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a8y9vs